# Why I'm always getting presence type is unavailable?

Tags: android

I have developed simple chat application in which have used asmack lib and openfire server.
But when I starting chat using same I'm always getting presence status unavailable, where as that user is available on openfire server.

Have tried various things, have tested same code for talk.google.com server it works very well. Here I'm setting presence state of user-

```
                  Presence presence  = new Presence(Presence.Type.available); ; 
                  presence.setStatus("Online, Programmatically!");
                  presence.setPriority(24);
                  presence.setMode(Presence.Mode.available);
                  connection.sendPacket(presence);
                  try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                  } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                  }
```

and when I'm displaying roster entries I'm getting presence status is null, and presence type is unavailable, I don't know why it would happen, have tried various things. I'm testing my code on two different emulator on same machine. Is it due to same?

Here is code which displays the roster entries and type of presence

```
                   Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
                  Roster.setDefaultSubscriptionMode(Roster.SubscriptionMode.accept_all);
                  roster.addRosterListener(new RosterListener() {
                      // Ignored events public void entriesAdded(Collection<String> addresses) {}
                      public void entriesDeleted(Collection<String> addresses) {}
                      public void entriesUpdated(Collection<String> addresses) {}
                      public void presenceChanged(Presence presence) {
                          System.out.println("Presence changed: " + presence.getFrom() + " " + presence);
                      }
                      @Override
                      public void entriesAdded(Collection<String> arg0) {
                          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                      }
                  });
                  try { Thread.sleep(5000); } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
                  Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();                
                  for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {                           
                      Presence subscribed = new Presence(Presence.Type.subscribed); 
                      subscribed.setTo(entry.getUser()); 
                      connection.sendPacket(subscribed);

                      Log.d("JWP", "RosterEntry " + entry);
                      Log.d("JWP", "User: " + entry.getUser());
                      Log.d("JWP", "Name: " + entry.getName());
                      Log.d("JWP", "Status: " + entry.getStatus());
                      Log.d("JWP", "Type: " + entry.getType());               
                      Presence entryPresence = roster.getPresence(entry.getUser());
                      Log.d("JWP", "Presence Status: "+ entryPresence.getMode());
                      Log.d("JWP", "Presence Type: " + entryPresence.getType());

                      Presence.Type type = entryPresence.getType();
                      if (type == Presence.Type.available){
                          Log.d("JWP", "Presence AVIALABLE");
                          Log.d("JWP", "Presence : " + entryPresence);
                      }
                  }
```